# Release and cast data of a unique_ptr to another without copying

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

I have a unique_ptr of an array of floats that I would like to change to a unique_ptr of an array of uint8_t in my function. In other words, `unique_ptr<float[]>` --> `unique_ptr<uint8_t[]>`.

This is what I have tried

```cpp
void my_function(std::unique_ptr<float*> data) {
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t*> converted_data(reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(data.release()));

    // ...
    // Processing converted_data ...
}
```

Since I am getting this error: **`no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::unique_ptr<uint8_t *>'`**, I was wondering if it is possible to achieve this goal without copying the data.

Comment: "I have a unique_ptr of an array of floats that I would like to change to a unique_ptr of an array of uint8_t" - sounds like a really bad idea. *Why* do you think you want/need this? There's probably a better way.

Comment: `std::unique_ptr<float*>` should be a `unique_ptr<float[]>`

Comment: This is weird. The core issue is that `data.release()` returns a `float**` (note two stars!) and while `reinterpret_cast` will break a lot of rules, it won't do that. If you change it to cast to `uint8_t**`, it compiles. But it's still dangerous and probably not doing what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You are casting to an incompatible type.

data.release() is of type float** since it returns a raw pointer to whatever was in the unique_ptr (float* in this case). You should cast to uint_8t** instead ( though it still looks like a bad idea).